# How to get newly created id? DJANGO

Tags: python, django

I have two tables that are linked together, the Delivery table and Stock table. They are linked together by the delivery_id being a foreign key in the Stock table. My dilemma is that I have to get the newly created ID from the Delivery form  to my Stock form. How do I do it?

```
def delivery(request):

    form = DeliveryForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {"form": form}
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        context = {"message": "Success!"}
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/post/') 
    else:
        return render(request, 'inventorysystem/delivery.html', context)

def stock(request, delivery_id=id):

     form = StockForm(request.POST or None)
     context = {"form": form}
     if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        context = {"message": "Success!"}
     return render(request,'inventorysystem/post.html', context)
```

Comment: please post code and not screenshot

Comment: What do you mean with "get ID from delivery form to stock form"? These are different requests. You need to encode "everything" you need to render the request in the request itself (of course cookies and database can help).

Answer (score 1):

Well, to help with your code, you should have posted your model codes. But anyway, to 'link' the models you should follow these steps in your code:

## Instantiating models and Creating Relationships

This step is about to create a variable that refers to the Delivery model.

```
from YourApp.models import Delivery, Stock

q = Delivery(SomeField = 'Example', OtherField = 2)
```

Now, 'q' is holding the object that you want to make the relationship with Stock. So the next step is instantiate Stock in some variable and then make the reference to the field 'delivery' in the Stock model to the delivery object that we previously created. ( Note: The model Stock needs a field like this one delivery = models.ForeignKey(delivery, on_delete=models.CASCADE))

```
z = Stock(SomeField = 'Example3', delivery=q)
```

That's it. You can check if it worked using the django shell or manually in your database.
Hope it helps you at least a bit.